# Getting errors when I try and condense my code down ( C )

Tags: c

So I have this piece of code I've been trying to simplify, as when I type it out as is each line is stupidly long.

This is the piece of code and the error I keep getting: It's a Bellman Ford algorithm.

```
void BellmanFord (struct graph*graphs, struct point * pointer, struct city* startCity, struct city* destinationCity)
{
    char * name;
    //char * finalRoute;

    // creating new arrays
    int nEdge = graphs -> nEdge;
    int nVert = graphs -> nVert;

    //tracks energy expenditure
    int energy[nVert];

    // tracks path travelled
    //int nTravel = nEdge; ///trial

    // I added this to try solve the error, it didn't work
    //struct city*citiesVisited[nVert];

    int i;
    int j;

    // sets the start city as 0, assigns the rest to infinite
    for (i = 0; i < nVert; i++); ///should it be 0?
    {
        //startCity = graphs -> cities[i];
        energy[i] = INT_MAX;
       //citiesVisited[i] = pointConstructor(begin, end, INT_MAX);
    }

    //energy

    // graph searches for a more energy efficient route
    for (i = 1; i < nVert; i++);
    {
        // edges checked
        for ( j = 0; j < nEdge; j++);
        {
            struct road * roads;
            ///int road1 = graphs -> roads[j];

            ///experimental
            int startRoute = roads -> startCity;
            int endRoute = roads -> destinationCity;
            int weight = roads -> energy;
            int travelling = roads -> destinationCity -> nCitiesVisited;

            if (energy[endRoute] > energy[startRoute] + weight);
            {
                if (thisSeemsFamiliar(endRoute, startRoute) == 0);
                {
                    // stops loops
                    if (endRoute == startCity);
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                struct city * cities;

                energy[endRoute] = energy[startRoute] + weight;

(these two lines give me the error " citiesVisited / nCitiesVisited undeclared, first use in this function)

                (citiesVisited[travelling])[endRoute] = startRoute;
                nCitiesVisited[endRoute]++;
   
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

however, they are both declared here:

```
//vertex representing the cities
struct city
{
    char* cityName;
    //int volume;
    struct point*first;
    struct point*last;
    int energy;
    int nCitiesVisited;
    struct city*citiesVisited[100];

};
```

When the two lines are written as below, I get no errors, but I REALLY want to condense them down, help??

```
    roads -> destinationCity -> citiesVisited [roads -> destinationCity -> nCitiesVisited] = roads -> startCity;

roads -> destinationCity -> nCitiesVisited++;
```

Comment: Just a tip, when you are trying to build a solution try breaking it down into more "pieces". By breaking a problem into subproblems that are solved independantly, you have a better chance of it working. A great way of breaking it down is to use more procedures. An example of some procedures: CreateCityGraph(), TraverseRoute(), CalculateEnergyOfSubgraph() .etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "stupidly long" lines in the code presented.  The longest is the first line of the function definition, but I would address that simply by splitting it over two lines.  You could do the same with the first of the two lines you called out specifically.

More importantly, I don't see any excessively *complex* lines or statements.  You can make lines of code arbitrarily long by using verbose identifiers and whitespace, so the length in characters is not a particularly good evaluation criterion for anything other than ease of human reading.

You write:

> (these two lines give me the error " citiesVisited / nCitiesVisited
> undeclared, first use in this function)
>
> ```
>                 (citiesVisited[travelling])[endRoute] = startRoute;
>                 nCitiesVisited[endRoute]++;
> ```

Well yes, of course they do.  It's unclear to me why you would suppose that replacing `roads -> destinationCity -> citiesVisited` with `citiesVisited` would not alter the meaning of the code, or similarly for `nCitiesVisited`, at least without any other changes.  However, you could reduce repetition somewhat and thereby abbreviate the code by recording the value of `roads -> destinationCity` in a variable.  For example,

```
struct city *destination = roads->destinationCity;

// ...

                destination->citiesVisited[travelling][endRoute] = startRoute;

                // ...

                destination->nCitiesVisited[endRoute]++;
```

In that light, I furthermore note that you already have ...

> ```
>         int endRoute = roads -> destinationCity;
> ```

... which appears to be wrong.  All (other) indications are that the type of `roads->destinationCity` is `struct city *`, and

1. You need an explicit cast to convert a pointer into an integer, though some compilers might accept the castless conversion as an extension.  Your compiler ought at least to be warning you about that in any case.
2. It is very unlikely that the result of the conversion is appropriate for use as an array index, as in fact the posted code attempts to use `endRoute`.